# What about GDAL and GRASS GIS installation?

Tags: python, gdal, grass-gis

Is GRASS GIS included in the installation of GDAL on windows? Or do I need to install it separately?

How can I use GRASS GIS?
My environments:
Windows 10
Anaconda 3 (python3.6 , GDAL 3.0.4 installed)

Comment: Read first https://grass.osgeo.org/ and https://gdal.org and try to formulate more focused questions. GDAL does not know that GRASS exists. GRASS can use GDAL for some operations and may depend on GDAL nowadays even GRASS has a longer history.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Grass personally but the [OSGeo installer](https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe) makes all of these much easier on Windows platforms.  I would recommend using their installers for all of these.  You can also pick and choose which applications you want to install and get access to your QGIS python install much easier.